# Disabling Mouse Rightclick on WInforms

Tags: winforms

I have Windows Forms application and I need to disable MouseRightclick on my Application except on some controls..is there any generalize method to do so...or i have to disable it on each controls?
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A right-click doesn't do anything until *you* give it a meaning.  Like setting a control's ContextMenuStrip property or writing an event handler for the MouseDown event.  A few controls do have predefined behavior, TextBox for example has its own baked-in context menu.  You don't want to disable it.

So disable it by simply not doing anything to make it work.  IMessageFilter is indeed the only other hack.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way - [Capturing Mouse Events from every component on C# WInForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804374/capturing-mouse-events-from-every-component-on-c-winform)