# Capture mouse events outside of the control

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like my textbox to close itself when i click elsewhere, how can I do this?

I've seen `Control.Capture` which seems to grab the mouse events, but it doesn't work.

I also tried `Control.Leave` and `Control.LostFocus` events but they're only triggered when I press the tab key or click on another text field.

By closing I mean remove it from it's parent, but the important thing here I think is the event

Comment: What do you meant by closing textbox? you mean hide?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Don't understand this too. You cannot close a textbox.

Comment: Actually I have an event on my button, when I click it i create a textbox to rename it, then i would like to close this box when I click away.

Comment: Add a handler to mouse move on the form, you can then hide the text box when the mouse moves over the form. You should think about what happens if the user does everything on keyboard though so you should probably subscribe to lost focus on the text box too

Comment: @BryanPeeters Again, What do you meant by **close**?

Comment: Should the textbox **only** disappear when you click somewhere else **in your application**, or should it also disappear if, for example, you click or ALT-TAB onto another application? What about tabbing from control to control in your application (not using the mouse)?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i mean remove it from its parent

Comment: @elgonzo any would be great

Comment: Then it rather looks like you are being interested in a 'control focus lost' event, correct?

Comment: @elgonzo Exactly, but what I tried didn't work when I click on a blank panel

Comment: Okay, i see. Look here for possible approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804374/capturing-mouse-events-from-every-component-on-c-sharp-winform  (and ofcourse keep the LostFocus event handler, for all the other cases).

Comment: @elgonzo Tank you, I got over this answer but I was hoping for something simpler :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the [WM_CAPTURECHANGED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message and check whether textbox contains focus but it is not captured, if so hide it.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    const int WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215;
    if (m.Msg == WM_CAPTURECHANGED)
    {
        if (!textBox1.Capture && textBox1.Focused && textBox1.Visible)
        {
            textBox1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to put this in your form where that textbox lives. Doesn't work is not helpful. Please tell what happens? I tried before posting and it worked. You keep the focus in textbox, then click somewhere texbox will hide automatically.

Comment: The textbox doesn't hide

Comment: Before clicking outside did you click the textbox first? If not do it and see. If still doesn't work post your updated code where you used this code, so that I can see where you're wrong.

Comment: I've the same code as you, I set it to visible and I tried with Capture to true and false, but the condition never true.

Comment: Okay I tried almost from scratch and it's working now, thank you :)