# c# register any MouseClick event on the Form

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseclick-event

I want to make an event that runs every time the mouse clicks anywhere on the form.

Currently i got it set this:

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form_MouseClick);
```

But this only works when not clicking on any other element like a panel
Is there any way i can override this?

Comment: [Capturing Mouse Events from every component on WInForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804374/capturing-mouse-events-from-every-component-on-c-sharp-winform)

Comment: i've seen those, but didnt find the answer i was looking for, Backs helped me down here

Comment: I've posted that link because if you combine what is proposed in that answer with @Backs answer, you have a class that can handle this task very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen `WndProc`, override method in your form class:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    //0x210 is WM_PARENTNOTIFY
    if (m.Msg == 0x210 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 513) //513 is WM_LBUTTONCLICK
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m); //You have a mouseclick(left)on the underlying user control
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to dynamically traverse through all the controls in the form and add the MouseClick event handler.
Please check this answer: [Handling a Click for all controls on a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247946/handling-a-click-for-all-controls-on-a-form)

Below code adds MouseClick event handler to the first level of controls:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
   c.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(
     delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
       // handle the click here
     });
 }
```

But if your controls have clild controld then you will have to recursively add the eventhandler:

```
void initControlsRecursive(ControlCollection coll)
 { 
    foreach (Control c in coll)  
     {  
       c.MouseClick += (sender, e) => {/* handle the click here  */});  
       initControlsRecursive(c.Controls);
     }
 }

/* ... */
initControlsRecursive(Form.Controls);
```