# c# how do i detect when a user clicks anywhere inside a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to have something happen when a user clicks anywhere inside the form. I don't know much about c# and I have tried looking it up but I just can't find an answer to this exact question.

Comment: What kind of form? Winforms? Web Forms? WPF?

Comment: "windows forms app" in visual studio

Comment: Implement the IMessageFilter interface.  Thinking that this is useful is a standard "don't know much" mistake.  You can't get the help you really need if you don't explain why you think you need it.

Comment: it seems you want to handle a click in the form, not in any of the contained controls (buttons, textbox and so on), you just have to handle the Click event of the form. anyway, an advice: if this is actually your problem, you should start looking for tutorials on C# and winforms, before start asking on SO. Learning a language, as a start, requires something different than asking questions on sites like this

Comment: Start by reading about the following events. Give something a try, and if you get stuck come back with a more specific question (including problematic code). These events are all related to clicking on a form: `MouseClick`, `MouseDoubleClick`, `MouseDown`, and `MouseUp`.

Comment: This is the best answer you will find if you want to handle all click globally (ps - Google is your friend) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804374/capturing-mouse-events-from-every-component-on-c-sharp-winform

Comment: Also related: [Handling a Click for all controls on a Form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/247946/3744182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's things called **events**

so when the event **is happen** the code will work

*for ex:*

**Click** : when I 'click', the code will happen and that's what are you looking for

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("hello world!");
}
```

All you have to do is select the event you want from the properties tab and double click on it and write the code you want

Answer (score 1):

try this

**1 --> go to form properties.**

**2 --> find Click event.**

**3 --> double Click it.**

[image]

code here

[image]